# how to fetch data seprately stored in single column stored with commas from db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching data from the first table this is fine and I am getting output. in this table data in column name 'std_list' is stored like 1,2,3,4,5,.. when I echo it gives output 1,2,3,4,5,.... but when I use this variable to get data from another table it uses only 1 to fetch data from other tables.

```
<span><?php echo $user['std_list'];?></span></p>        

<?php
    //$query="SELECT * FROM events Where std_list != '0' ";
$query="SELECT * FROM events where id='$eid'";
$showdata=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$user=mysql_fetch_array($showdata);
?>
```

on the basis of first table output i am trying to fetch data from another table.

```
          <?php
                $sid=$user['std_list'];
                //$query="SELECT * FROM events Where std_list != '0' ";
                $query="SELECT * FROM student_info where id='$sid'";
                $showstudent=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                while($students=mysql_fetch_array($showstudent))
                {
            ?>
```

this is my code the data stored in 'std_list' column is like 1,2,3,4,5,6..... and i want to fetch each  numeric seprately but according to my code it is only fetching first numeric only from other table.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqi_*

Comment: i didn't get you what your trying to do

Comment: show your table schema with 2-3 dummy data and your expected output for understanding your question.

Comment: i edited my question please check @JYoThI

Comment: i edited my question please check @Nidhi

Comment: try my below answer @yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use  `WHERE id IN ()`

1)  Mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

2) Use PDO or Prepared statement

```
$sid ='1,2,3,4,5,6';

$query="SELECT * FROM student_info where id IN (".$sid.")";
```

**Update 1:**

```
<?php

//db connection

$servername = "localhost";  //host name

$username = "username"; //username

$password = "password"; //password

$mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

//mysqli prepared statement 

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

    $sid ='1,2,3,4,5,6';
    $sid = explode(',',$sid);
    $total_items = count($sid);
    $question_marks = array_fill(0, $total_items, '?');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student_info where id IN (".$question_marks.")");
            $stmt->execute($sid);
            $get_result =$stmt->get_result();
            $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

            if($row_count>0){

                 while($row=$get_result->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                      print_r($row);
                  }
            }

?>
```

Comment: glad to help you @yogesh